# Can't login with google on android phone

Tags: android, google-signin

I have a problem with sign-in google on some android devices. It show the message "com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10". I have check the SHA1 key on https://console.firebase.google.com/ and the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs on https://console.cloud.google.com/. All config are right. I can login with samsung devices. But when use Huawei devices. I got the problem. Please help me to find the problem.

Comment: Make sure your Huawei device has Google Play Service to support this Firebase. Because Firebase & Google Auth depends on this Play Serivce.

Comment: Yes, my phone has google play service. After clear all cache of the app and reinstall. I can login again, but I don't understand the problem